# Maps passing to Quotient Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map between topological spaces and let $q_X:X\rightarrow Z$ and $q_Y:Y\rightarrow W$ be quotient maps.  Then, is there a unique map $F:Z\rightarrow W$ making the following diagram commute:

$$
F\circ q_X = q_Y\circ f?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "it depends".

You can define an equivalence relation $\sim_X$ on $X$ by $x_1\sim_X x_2$ if $q_X(x_1) = q_X(x_2)$ and similarly for $\sim_Y$ on $Y$. Then a necessary condition for $F$ to exist is that $f$ preserves the equivalence classes, i.e. that $x_1 \sim_X x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) \sim_Y f(x_2)$.

If I were to guess I would say that this condition is also sufficient, but right now I am not convinced it is true.

**Edit**: After a short search (i.e. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) ) I am quite confident that this condition is also sufficient. The space $Z$ "is" the quotient space $X/\sim_X$ and the properties of the quotient space ensures the existence of your map $F\colon X/\sim_X \to W$ (since by the condition mentionned above, $x_1 \sim_X x_2 \Rightarrow q_Y\circ f(x_1) = q_Y\circ f(x_2)$)

Comment: That makes sense, it's also very intuitive and "natural" (for a lack of a better word)